# Two finger tap selects text in web browsers

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, click, contextual-menu

[image: Demo GIF]

Because of the selection I see a different context menu and it's really annoying. How to change this behaviour? It's the same for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

[image: System Preferences → Trackpad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature implemented across the entirety of macOS, through web views and text areas. There is no option to disable it.

Comment: @IAfanasov What is it you're needing to right click without selecting the text for? Perhaps there's an alternative?

Comment: there is custom context menu. because text is selected, I see context menu of selected text instead of that custom menu